# ParseFloat Confusion

Tags: javascript, decimal

In my code, I have this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addNumbers()
    {
        var collect = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Collect").value);
        var current = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Current").value);
        var Balance = document.getElementById("Bal");
        Balance.value = collect + current;
    }
</script>
```

If, for example,the input is: 123.12 + 12.22, the Balance is 135.34
But if the input is : 123.00 + 12.00, the Balance is 135 instead of 135.00.

What should I add to achieve the 2nd output sample?

Thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - why not make an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ToFixed(2)` [**mdn**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

`(123.00 + 12.00).toFixed(2)` //135.00

Also , use || operator.

So :

```
function addNumbers()
{
    var collect = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Collect").value) ||0;
    var current = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Current").value) ||0;
    var Balance = document.getElementById("Bal");
    Balance.value = (collect + current).toFixed(2);
}
```

Small gotcha :

`(9.999 +9.999).toFixed(2)` //"20.00"

```
So how would I solve it ?
```

simply :

Multiply by 1000 each and then move decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `parseFloat()` is working correctly but it's the output that isn't quite to your liking. Try using [Number's `.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function for formatting:

```
Balance.value = (collect + current).toFixed(2)
```

There's some great discussions of formatting currency over on this question: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)